# While tokenizing the following string 40 println "Hello ",(5+6-4), "-4" is showing a single token and not separate one

Tags: java, regex, tokenize, lexer

I am writing a lexer in java for a custom base language. For the following line
40 println "Hello ",(5+6-4)
I want the output as

```
40
println
"Hello "
,
(
5
+
6
-
4
)
```

Everything else is coming alright, but for some reason i am getting - and 4 together "-4" as a token.

Regex used:

For Numbers `-?[0-9]+`
Special operator / Characters: `[\\[|\\]|/|.|$|*|-|+|=|>|<|#|(|)|%|,|!|||&|||{|}]`

Regex for Number without the leading "-" is showing error at char 89 which is start of **?**[0-9]+

```
dangling Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 89 ((?<Reserved>\bPRINTLN\b|\bPRINT\b|\bINTEGER\b|\bINPUT\b|\bEND\b|\bLET\b))|((?<Constants>?[0-9]+))|((?<Special>[\[|\]|/|.|$|*|-|+|=|>|<|#|(|)|%|,|!|||&|||{|}]))|((?<Literals>"[^"]*"))|((?<Identifiers>\w+))
```

I am storing the regex in a string and using named capturing grouping to identify the tokens.

Comment: Obviously your code isn't doing what you want it to do. Consider adding your code if you want us to help you fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<Constants>?[0-9]+)` - This part in your regex seems to be the problem. The `?` following the capture group name is a dangling one.

Also, there is no need to separate a character class members using `|`.

Based on the error you shared, the following would be what you want:

```
    String regex = "((?<Reserved>\\bPRINTLN\\b|\\bPRINT\\b|\\bINTEGER\\b|\\bINPUT\\b|\\bEND\\b|\\bLET\\b))|((?<Constants>[0-9]+))|((?<Special>[\\[\\]/.$*\\-+=><#()%,!|&{|}]))|((?<Literals>\"[^\"]*\"))|((?<Identifiers>\\w+))";
    String s = "40 println \"Hello \",(5+6-4) ";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

I have **removed the dangling `?`** mentioned above, **removed the `|`s** used for separation inside character class and **escaped the `-` inside the character class** (alternatively you can move the `-` to the end of the character class).

Answer (score 0):

We can't really tell what's going on because you haven't shown us your tokenizer.  However, I can take a guess: your tokenizer has logic in it to look for numeric literals before it looks for special characters, and it's accepting negative numbers as numeric literals.  As you can see, this creates ambiguity.

The simple solution is to only accept positive numeric literals as tokens, and treat `-` as a unary operator that negates its argument.  So `"-4+5"` would come out as four tokens: `"-"`, `"4"`, `"+"`, `"5"`.  The expression parser would then need to understand when `-` is a unary operator and when it's a binary operator, and act accordingly.  An advantage is that your program can now handle expressions like `"-(2+3)"` [I don't know whether it would have done that anyway].

Another possibility is for the tokenizer to be context-sensitive and behave differently depending on the previous token.  Thus, if `-` is at the beginning of the string or follows `(` or another operator, and if it's followed by a digit, the `-` is treated as the minus sign in a negative integer literal.  If it follows anything else, then it must be treated separately.  Most compilers can tokenize their input without having to keep track of the previous token, but there are exceptions.  In Ada, this causes some headache for compiler writers:

```
Record_Type'('A','B','C');
```

Normally, a single quote mark followed by a character followed by another single quote mark is a character literal, but an Ada compiler has to take special pains not to treat `'('` as a character literal.  The first quote mark means something different here.  The typical solution is to keep track of whether the previous token is an identifier.  (I used to maintain an Ada compiler, so I'm familiar with this case.)

Java may be another example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap;
```

Here, a compiler has to be careful about how it handles the `>>`.  Normally, this is a single token (meaning right shift), but it has to be treated as two `>` delimiters.  I haven't seen any Java compiler code, so I don't know how they handle it (do they tokenize it as a single `>>` and straighten things out later, or is it based on context?).

Anyway, I'm just throwing these out to point out that sometimes tokenization *does* have to be aware of context.  So if you adopt the second solution, it won't be unheard of.  But it does make things a little more difficult.